# How to pass data to other iOS application?

Tags: ios, share

How can I share some data (e.g. PDF or image) from my iOS application to other apps. I mean how to invoke the modal screen when user can choose the proper app to share my data with?
I cannot find any API but I am pretty sure that it exists.

Comment: Check out icloud service https://www.icloud.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [UIDocumentInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
UIDocumentInteractionController* docController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];
docController.URL = urlToFile;
```

Then present it

```
[docController presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:barBtnItem animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Communication between apps provides your application with an opportunity to take advantage of other application’s functionality, send and receive data between apps, and provide a rich user experience that “just works”.

Check This Tutorial [iOS SDK: Working with URL Schemes](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/) May be helpful for you.